# selecting incremental data from multiple tables in Hive

Tags: sql, apache, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have five tables(A,B,C,D,E) in Hive database and I have to union the data from these tables based on logic over column "id".

The condition is :

```
Select * from A
UNION 
select * from B (except  ids not in A)
UNION 
select * from C (except ids not in A and B)
UNION 
select * from D(except ids not in A,B and C)
UNION 
select * from E(except ids not in A,B,C and D)
```

Have to insert this data into final table.

One way is to create a the target table (target)and append it with data for each UNION stage and then using this table for joining with the other UNION stage.

**This would be the part of my .hql file :**

```
insert into target 
(select * from A
UNION 
select B.* from 
A 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B
on A.id=B.id
where ISNULL(A.id));

INSERT INTO target
select C.* from 
target 
RIGHT outer JOIN C
ON target.id=C.id
where ISNULL(target.id);

INSERT INTO target
select D.* from 
target 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN D
ON target.id=D.id
where ISNULL(target.id);

INSERT INTO target
select E.* from 
target 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN E
ON target.id=E.id
where ISNULL(target.id);
```

---

**Is there a better to make this happen ? I assume we anyway have to do the 
multiple joins/lookups .I am looking forward for best approach to achieve this
 in**

1) Hive with Tez

2) Spark-sql

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is unique within each table, then `row_number` can be used instead of `rank`.

```
select      *

from       (select      *
                       ,rank () over
                        (
                            partition by    id
                            order by        src
                        )                           as rnk

            from        (           
                                    select 1 as src,* from a
                        union all   select 2 as src,* from b
                        union all   select 3 as src,* from c
                        union all   select 4 as src,* from d
                        union all   select 5 as src,* from e
                        ) t
            ) t

where       rnk = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try to do this as:

```
with ids as (
      select id, min(which) as which
      from (select id, 1 as which from a union all
            select id, 2 as which from b union all
            select id, 3 as which from c union all
            select id, 4 as which from d union all
            select id, 5 as which from e
           ) x
     )
select a.*
from a join ids on a.id = ids.id and ids.which = 1
union all
select b.*
from b join ids on b.id = ids.id and ids.which = 2
union all
select c.*
from c join ids on c.id = ids.id and ids.which = 3
union all
select d.*
from d join ids on d.id = ids.id and ids.which = 4
union all
select e.*
from e join ids on e.id = ids.id and ids.which = 5;
```

Comment: Way too complicated.